# setInterval refuses to run my function after recent edit to my code... why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

To give you a grasp of what I mean in my title.

Take a look at this code which is before the setInterval stopped working.

```
var anime = function(){
    _.each(db.get('','animedb'), function(site){
        var ann = function(){
```

^ the function is in a var

```
for (var epid in eps) {
    epid = parseInt(epid, 10);
    var eptime = (new Date(eps[epid].pubDate[0])*1000)/1000;
    if(eptime > site.lastbuilddate){
        counter = counter+1;
        if(counter < 6){
            list.push(font(colors['normal'])+eps[epid].title[0] +' - ['+ utils.secondsToString((new Date() - (eptime+site.delay))/1000, 1)+' ago.]</f>');
        }
    }
};
```

^ this is the part that breaks everything after its been edited

```
var run = setInterval(ann, site.interval*60000);
```

^ here is the setInterval its at the bottom of the each

```
anime();
```

^ here is the call for the whole function that calls the setInterval

The above code is part of an anime announcement for chat rooms owned by anime sites owners using their rss feeds.

The above code works and excuse me for saying this but at this point.
I'm going to say "I have no idea why". Because i really have no idea why setInterval picks and chooses when to work.
I talked to a friend who had more knowledge than me in javascript and time based functions and he said that there are no "conditions" required for setInterval to run.

```
for (var epid in eps) {
    epid = parseInt(epid, 10);
    var eptime = (new Date(eps[epid].pubDate[0])*1000)/1000;
    if(eptime > site.lastbuilddate){
        counter = counter+1;
        if(counter < 6){
            var url = eps[epid].link.split('//')[1];
            var keyword = '';
            var words = url.substr(0, url.length-1).split('/').join('-').split('-');
            for (var wid in words) {
                keyword += words[wid].charAt(0);
            }
            http.get({hostname:'dev.ilp.moe', port:80, path:'/surl/yourls-api.php?username=usernameremovedforsecurity&password=passwordremovedforsecurity&format=json&action=shorturl&url='+url+'&title='+ctitle+' - '+eps[epid].title[0]+'&keyword='+keyword}, function(r) {
                if(r.statusCode === 200) { //200 is success
                    var b = '';
                    r.on('data', function(c) {
                        b += c;
                    });
                    r.on('end', function() {
                        list.push(font(colors['normal'])+eps[epid].title[0] +' - ['+ utils.secondsToString((new Date() - (eptime+site.delay))/1000, 1)+' ago.] - http://dev.ilp.moe/surl/'+keyword+'</f>');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

The above code is the part for creating shorturls.

Here is the json DB that is being loaded.

```
{"0":{"lastbuilddate":1426441081000,"delay":0,"host":"www.animerush.tv","path":"/rss.xml","chats":["animerushtv"],"interval":15},"1":{"lastbuilddate":1424068119000,"delay":28800000,"host":"dubbedanime.tv","path":"/feed/","chats":["dubbed-anime-tv"],"interval":15},"2":{"lastbuilddate":1426415086000,"delay":32400000,"host":"bestanimes.tv","path":"/feed/","chats":["bestanimestv"],"interval":15},"3":{"lastbuilddate":1426434866000,"delay":0,"host":"www.theanime.tv","path":"/feed/","chats":["timecapsule"],"interval":15}}
```

The recent edit to my code was supposed to implement Shortened links for each episode released using the links provided in the rss feeds from the sites in the database.

The domain http://ilp.moe is my domain.

I have console logged everywhere and tested as much as I possibly could. 
At this point I do not understand why the edit is making code that used to be executed by setInterval no longer be executed.

Comment: On the one hand we have the chance of a core library function failing "sometimes".  On the other hand we have your code which at times displays a lack of basic error handling.  Given that if setInterval failed there'd be a LOT of bug reports about it, I'm going to bet that your code has some kind of error that's causing failure.  I'd start with stepping through your code to see exactly what's being executed and where any issues might be.

Comment: I have done so i placed a console log everywhere. setInterval for some reason isn't running my code at all to even get to the console.log() i placed. I could try to run the code without setInterval and see if it runs or if it errors. If it doesn't error than it would seem that the former you mentioned is actually happening. This wouldn't be the first time this has happened to me either. @Paul

Comment: While stepping through your code, do you even get to setInterval being executed?  If you set a break point on it, does it get there?  What if you `setInterval(function () { console.log("Got here.  Yay."); }, ...` ?  What do you see when you debug it?

Comment: can you put a `console.log()` after ` _.each(db.get('','animedb'), function(site){` line and tell me what happens?

Comment: @mido22 well color me funny but tell me why after i added a console.log(site) after where you told me to setInterval started to work and started showing me errors in my log

Comment: @pual my code has an error logger in another section the problem was mainly that i was getting no uncaught exceptions until just now.
i don't understand why it started to work after mido22 had me put the console log before the setInterval

Comment: @pual I normally assume that setInterval would still run the code and tell me through an uncaught exception that there is a problem with my code. Instead setInterval does nothing ? that's rather confusing.
Not trying to make this question a bug report but i do believe that there should be some testing of the setInterval function to make sure it runs even if there are errors.

Comment: my best guess might be, both statments inside _.each are variable assignments, and hence did not throw error, but it sounds absurd...

Comment: @mido22 I agree with you. However at this point I have no other reason to believe otherwise.

Comment: This is **way** too much code for anyone to wade through. You are giving us two versions as well; we are supposed to diff them in our heads? The guidelines are "shortest code necessary to reproduce". Please strip down your code to a simple case. As a useful side benefit, while doing that, you will likely find the problem yourself.

Comment: In this case shortest code wasn't exactly short. The problem was mainly that the setInterval function refused to execute because of errors. and because of that the errors were not shown. @torazaburo
deleting this 
will undelete if i deem necessary

Comment: @torazaburo undeleted because i edited a bit
i need help editing this though as i'm not sure what else to remove
without ruining the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the code wasn't executed is because the functions were assigned to a variable so they weren't run until it got to setInterval.

When they reach setInterval the errors prevent setInterval from executing (depends on the severity of the error).

after taking the function and just running it without putting it in a var or setInterval and console logging for a bit i found the error was caused by this line

```
var url = eps[epid].link.split('//')[1];
```

in this case

```
eps[epid].link; // === ["http://blah.com/animelolep1"]
```

my problem was that the var url was trying to split on a list and not a string

here is the fix

```
var url = eps[epid].link[0].split('//')[1]; // grabs the first item from the list and then splits
```